# jQuery to get an image from server and display as popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I have images in a server, and I want them to be displayed as a popup.

The workflow is as follow:

1- I get the id of the row where I want to display the image.
2- I make an Ajax call using the id in order to get the image name from the server.
3- I return the image as an < a >, like this:

```
 $options2.= "<a href=\"/js/images/up/".$name."\"\" data-jbox-image=\"gallery1\" title=\"My image\"><img src=\"/js/images/up/".$name."\"\" alt=\"\"></a>";
```

4- But on receiving this I have to display it as a popup. There's where I'm struck. I can show it in a div. But how do I show it in a popup?

5- I searched and got a popup for it like this- but i am getting the image **dynamically** , so dont know how to apply this.

```
new jBox('Image');

   <a href="/image1_large.jpg" title="My title 1" data-jbox-image="gallery1"><img src="/image1_small.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

Please give me some guidance.

### EDIT

Alsoi have no image in the current page just a button where i want to use ajax call to **return back the image as popup**

Comment: Use `colorbox`. it's really easy. [http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Comment: You can use JQuery UI and its dialog.

Comment: @ Hoijof : can u give how this is done in ajax success function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) for this. It's a jQuery-Plugin like jBox, but easier to use.

Code Sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a.imageLink").fancybox();

});
```

```html
<a class="imageLink" href="image_big.jpg"><img src="image_small.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Use this code to open the fancybox on your ajax success function:

```js
$.fancybox({
  'href'            : returnVal,
  'title'           : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'transitionIn'    : 'elastic',
  'transitionOut'   : 'elastic'
});
```

Comment: thanks.. in my ajax success function, how shall i produce this as a popup window.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check it!

Comment: how to insert my variable inside it. i tried with >:  but its not working `  'href'            : '+returnval+',`

Comment: thanks sir,...this time the popup appears with :  " The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later. "

Comment: What's in `returnval`? Can you open the image in the browser?

Comment: yes of course.... it have the full path. in the browser console it says :The requested URL "/MY_IP_ADDRS/js/images/up/rs7-by-brendan.jpg" was not found on this server.

Comment: The path `/MY_IP_ADDRS/js/images/up/rs7-by-brendan.jpg` is no URL, it's a relative path. Are you developing on a local webserver (http://localhost)? You should check your image paths.

Comment: yes..i rechecked and it was :  /MY_IP_ADDRS/MY_IP_ADDRS/js/images/up/rs7-by-brendan.jpg...

Answer (score 1):

Try using Jquery-ui http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
$("#your-div-id-with-the-img").dialog();
```